# Django Rest Framework: empty list when using RelatedField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following django models

```
class Cast(models.Model):
    coordinates = models.PointField()

class CastImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="castimages")
    cast = models.ForeignKey(Cast, blank=True, null=True, related_name='images')
```

and the following serializer

```
class CastSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Cast
        fields = ('images',)
```

This all seems quite similar to what can be found in the doc: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#relatedfield

but when I test the serializer for the Cast object, although there really are images for those Cast objects (I checked), I only get empty images lists:

```
"results": [
        {
            "images": []
        }, 
        {
            "images": []
        }, 
        {
            "images": []
        } ]
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Shoudln't that be `model = CastImage`?

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer, but no, it's really Cast. I want to show the CastImage instances that have a foreign key pointing at my Cast instances, as explained here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#relatedfield

Answer (score 1):

If you're accessing the images through `Cast`, my guess would be that your fields are wrong.
How about

```
class CastSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  images = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
  class Meta:
    model = Cast
    fields = ('castimage__image',)
```

Comment: No, I do not think that is the problem: it just does not load the images, which it should, since I use the right "related_name".